# Counting the number of possibilities to build a vector of length 20

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to count all the vectors of length $20$ that contains $i$ times the number $i$ and $j$ times the number $j$ where $i,j\in\{1,...,6\}$. The vector can contain any number in the set $\{1,...,6\}$.

The solution in my book: We will choose $i$ places out of $20$ where we will place the number $i$ in $20 \choose i$. Also we will choose $j$ places out of $20-i$ where we will put $j$ in $20-i \choose j$. In other $20-i-j$ places we have the other $\{1,...,6\}\backslash\{i,j\}$ numbers. So the result is:

$$
{20 \choose i}{20-i \choose j}
$$

I don't understand why they did not continue counting the number of possibilities to place the other numbers  $\{1,...,6\}\backslash\{i,j\}$. They only counted the number of possibilities to place $i$ and $j$. What about the rest? I will be glad to have an explanation.

Comment: Not sure the rules are clear.  $1+2+3+4+5+6=21$  so you can't pass your test for all $i\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.  Are you saying that you want this condition met for exactly two of those six digits?  At least two?  Something else?

Comment: @lulu only two of those digits fulfil this condition. For example, $5$ and $6$. So $5$ will be placed $5$ times and $6$ will be placed $6$. Other $\{1,2,3,4\}$ will be in the other $20-6-5=9$ places (does not matter how).

Comment: Are $i,j$ specified in advance?

Comment: @lulu No, we just know that $i\neq j$.

Comment: but then your answer should sum over the choices $i,j$...and you have to subtract the cases that are multiply counted.

Answer (score 1):

As the question is written, the other $20-i-j$ places have four choices each (anything except $i$ and $j$), so the book solution should be  multiplied by $4^{20-i-j}$